# Inject dynamic value in readme in github

Tags: github, readme

I am writing a document in github but I want to a user entered name injected in code block so that user can copy paste it once he has entered the blank with a name

something like this
Enter project name:_______

```
<property name="SVC_NAME" value="_______"/>
```

has anyone done this or know if it even possible in github?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub doesn't allow any sort of dynamic content in READMEs.  That's for multiple reasons, including privacy and security (running user-provided JavaScript is a security problem) and caching (creating dynamic content server side would prevent useful caching from taking place).

The idea of a README is that it should be a document that describes your project.  That should be true whether the user is reading it on GitHub or in a pager in a  clone of your project, where they will not have a web browser to interact with your content.

You could provide an example script to generate the data that prompts the user for the input or determines it based on the directory they're running it in and demonstrate how to use that in your README, or you could just instruct the user that they should fill in the blank with an appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically use a github Action to autogenerate your `README.MD` when certain triggers fire. The `README.MD` will be static (not via includes, like in docsify). See for example this file: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-s-readme-generator

You would NOT be able to easily trigger based on user input in a browser.

You could write your own webpage to generate the correct line of code. And then link to it. If it's something like filling in 1 blank, then just telling the user is probably easier. However, if there are many places where this configuration string is needed, then a script might make more sense.